# Content disappears or appears randomly Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

Strange bug I fixed once in the past but did not write it down/document it/report it so now I'm lost in the same workframe.

So, it's an Angular 2 app, the content is hardcoded html, no Angular binded variables, data banding or similar.

The bug show up on Chrome, not on Firefox.

If I refresh 10 times in a row, the content will show up sometimes and won't others, there is no pattern or clues about it.

Once the content is hidden, if i change whatever element property, will show up all the content instantly.

I have attached a gif which explains the bug clearly.

Thanks for any idea/suggestion/help :)

[image]

EDIT 1:

I just added 2 pictures of the css computed, one with Bootstrap 4 and other without the framework, same result.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not related at all to Angular or any stuff like that.

I am importing a font from the GoogleFonts page. If I download this font, I get **TTF** format, which is having a bug on Chrome and does not work properly, but if I link to their server, it's using **WOFF2** format.

See this picture attached which it shows the different formats for the same font.

[image]